# Unable to connect to localhost when I want to connect my sql workbench with cloud AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I want to do the test hahaha, that I have to access their database. I already install my sql web community installer and I did it.

I can connect to my own username and pass, but when I want to access database in AWS Cloud, it became like  this[image]

i's been a long time I didnt manage to work with sql. I just do the queries, I never do this at the start.
Thank you so much if anyone want to help

Answer (score 0):

Two things you need to make this happen.

1. Make sure you have configured your RDS instance to allow public access.
2. Make sure you have properly setup the inbound rules to let the IP of your development machine access your RDS instance. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html.

Once you do these, you can connect as shown here:

[image]

Comment: yes thank you sir! @smac2020 the one who can solve is them, and they already fixed it. Thank You so much !!